# How do I still get the content of the file when it was moved to another directory in shell script?

Tags: shell, unix

I created a symbolic link to the file, then the file was moved to another place with different name. How can I get the content of the old file through the symbolic link ? At the moment, the symbolic link is not valid because the target no longer exists.

Thank you.

Comment: Is is a soft link or hard link?

Answer (score 0):

Hard links point to file contents (actually the inode).  Symbolic links point to the pathname.  If the old name is gone, then you cannot get to the file using the link.

Comment: Sure, are there any solutions ? at the moment, I think i can use find with [OPTION] -lname; however, I can't find anything as well. @stark

Comment: Thank you, I think I could have an answer for this :)

Comment: You could match modification times on the old directory to any new files.